# ASP MVC 4 Web Api wraps my json result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My WebApi action returns a dynamic object built from JObject.parse(jsonString);

I have GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

But that object is wrapped inside a default result message in the response.

According to this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_anon) returning anonymous objects is fine and should give the expected result

I am using an async controller because I have to await some ReadAsStringAsync() here the protoype of my action:

```
public async Task<dynamic> Pics(string flavor, int pagesize)
```

Expected result :

```
{"flavor":"","maxFeedSize":0,"mediaContent":[]}
```

Result I have when returning the dynamic object:

```
{
        "Result": {
            "flavor": "",
            "maxFeedSize": 0,
            "mediaContent": []
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "Exception": null,
        "Status": 5,
        "IsCanceled": false,
        "IsCompleted": true,
        "CreationOptions": 0,
        "AsyncState": null,
        "IsFaulted": false
    }
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking.  What is the behavior you're expecting, and what behavior are you actually getting?

Comment: By the looks of things you're getting a serialized `Task<dynamic>`... can you post all of your controller action code?

Answer (score 1):

As I thought and as mentioned in comments. I was returning a `Task<Task<dynamic>>` because of a naive method overload.

```
    public async Task<dynamic> Pics(string flavor, string pagesize)
    {
        return Pics(flavor, pagesize, null);
    }
```

Edit:
I tried this because unlike MVC routes ommit a string parameter throws an error even if string is nullable

```
  public async Task<dynamic> Pics(string flavor, string pagesize, string startid =null)
```

works fine :)

Comment: Or you could make your overload non-`async` (tip: listen to your compiler warnings). Like this: `public Task<dynamic> Pics(string flavor, string pagesize) { return Pics(flavor, pagesize, null); }`